Deallocation runtime issue using references to vectors in threads in C++
I have implemented threads that use references to vectors, and won't change the same value at the same time based on the notification system I added so there shouldn't be any issues with atomicity. I think. There might be with the isAnyOne boolean but they will set to the same value so there shouldn't be a race condition, I hope.
I can't find the solution to the runtime issue I am getting. This issue is like a breakpoint when running with the debugger as it is causing a memory leak.
The issue is that at the end of the coe being run the debugger points me to here:

The full code for the program is shown below:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;

const uint8_t BASE = 10;
mutex mtx;
condition_variable cv;

void OutputList(vector<uint8_t> &inputNumbers) {
    for (int i = 0; i < inputNumbers.size(); i++) {
        if (i == inputNumbers.size() - 1) {
            cout << unsigned(inputNumbers[i]) << " ]";
        }
        else if (i == 0) {
            cout << "[ " << unsigned(inputNumbers[i]) << ", ";
        }
        else {
            cout << unsigned(inputNumbers[i]) << ", ";
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

// Set the doneThreads item at threadIndex to true when operation done.
void ThreadHandler(vector<int> &doneThreads, int threadIndex, bool &finishedIterations, vector<uint8_t> &input, vector<int> &startIndexes, vector<int> &endIndexes, vector<uint8_t> &output, vector<uint8_t> &carries, int &iterationCount, bool &isAnyOne) {
    // Continue processing until all iterations are finished
    while (!finishedIterations) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx); // Acquire a unique lock on the mutex to ensure thread safety
        cv.wait(lock, [&doneThreads, threadIndex] {
            // If all threads aren't done then start
            return doneThreads[threadIndex] == 0;
        });

        // Do Work Here
        cout << "Doing Work on thread!" << endl;
        for (int i = startIndexes[threadIndex]; i < endIndexes[threadIndex]; i++) {
            uint8_t intermediate = input[i] + input[input.size() - (i + 1)];
            uint8_t localCarry = (intermediate >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
            output[i] = localCarry ? intermediate - 10 : intermediate;
            carries[i+1] = localCarry;
            if (localCarry == 1) {
                isAnyOne = true;
            }
        }
        // Mark this thread's work as done for the current iteration
        doneThreads[threadIndex] += 1;
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
    }
}

void ControllerThread(int &iterationCount, bool &finishedIterations, vector<int> &doneThreads, vector<int> &startIndexes, vector<int> &endIndexes, vector<uint8_t> &output, vector<uint8_t> &carries, bool &isAnyOne, int numThreads, vector<uint8_t> &input) {
    iterationCount = 0;
    while(iterationCount < 10) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [&doneThreads] {
            // If all threads are done then start
            return all_of(doneThreads.begin(), doneThreads.end(), [](int done) {return done >= 1;});
        });

        cout << "Running main code!" << endl;

        // Set conditions for threads
        int itemsPerThread = input.size() / numThreads;
        // If the input size and number of threads aren't divisible
        int lastThreadExcess = input.size() % numThreads;
        // Initializing all the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            int startIndex = i * itemsPerThread;
            int endIndex = (i+1) * itemsPerThread;
            if (i == numThreads - 1) {
                endIndex += lastThreadExcess;
            }
            startIndexes[i] = startIndex;
            endIndexes[i] = endIndex;
        }

        // Carry propogation area
        while (isAnyOne) {
            isAnyOne = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < carries.size(); i++) {
                uint8_t intermediate;
                if (output.size() > i) {
                    intermediate = output.at(i) + carries.at(i);
                    carries[i] = 0;
                    uint8_t localCarry = (intermediate >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
                    if (localCarry == 1) {
                        isAnyOne = true;
                        intermediate -= 10;
                        if (carries.size() > i)
                            carries[i+1] = localCarry;
                        else
                            carries.push_back(localCarry);
                    }
                    output[i] = intermediate;
                }
                else if (carries[i] > 0) {
                    intermediate = carries.at(i);
                    carries[i] = 0;
                    output.push_back(intermediate);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        OutputList(output);

        // Resetting the threads to start doing tasks again
        for (int j = 0; j < doneThreads.size(); j++) {
            doneThreads[j] = 0;
        }
        // Starting the threads to do their tasks
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
        if (iterationCount > 0) {
            input = output;
        }
        iterationCount++;
    }
    // This top section of thread processing is finished so setting this variable
    finishedIterations = true;
}

int main() {
    vector<uint8_t> inputNumbers;
    int startNumber = 196;
    int quotient = startNumber;
    while (quotient != 0) {
        uint8_t remainder = quotient % 10;
        // Add the remainder to the list
        inputNumbers.push_back(remainder);
        // Get the new quotient
        quotient = quotient / 10;
    }
    // OutputList(inputNumbers);
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    {
        vector<uint8_t> output(inputNumbers.size(), 0);
        vector<uint8_t> carries(inputNumbers.size() + 1, 0);
        vector<thread> handles;
        int numThreads = 1;
        if (numThreads > inputNumbers.size()) {
            numThreads = inputNumbers.size();
        }
        vector<int> doneThreads(numThreads, 0);
        vector<int> startIndexes(numThreads, 0);
        vector<int> endIndexes(numThreads, 0);
        bool finishedIterations = false;
        int iterationCount = 0;
        bool isAnyOne = false;

        // Set up the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            handles.emplace_back(ThreadHandler, ref(doneThreads), i, ref(finishedIterations), ref(inputNumbers), ref(startIndexes), ref(endIndexes), ref(output), ref(carries), ref(iterationCount), ref(isAnyOne));
        }

        // Set up the controller thread, for the iterating through
        thread controller(ControllerThread, ref(iterationCount), ref(finishedIterations), ref(doneThreads), ref(startIndexes), ref(endIndexes), ref(output), ref(carries), ref(isAnyOne), numThreads, ref(inputNumbers));

        // Join all threads once all operations have happened
        for (auto &handle : handles) {
            handle.join();
        }
        controller.join();
    }
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = duration_cast<milliseconds>(stop - start);
    cout << "Number generated that is: " << inputNumbers.size() << " in length and took : " << duration.count() << " ms" << endl;
    // OutputList(inputNumbers);
    return 0;
}

Thank you for any help. I have no clue why this is happening.
I have tried changing to smart pointers and adding the atomicity that I thought may be a problem but there has been no luck. Any solutions to this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Please try to simplify your code, removing parts of it until the problem disappears. Then add back one line at a time until the problem returns. Use that knowledge to create a [mre] that you can easily debug. Perhaps even start over with an empty main function, adding one or two lines at a time. And try to avoid the treading for debugging, it tend to make it much harder to debug. Also remember to build with extra warnings, and perhaps a sanitizer.

I have not tried to fully understand your code but valgrind returns a Invalid write of size 1 on the line carries[i+1] = localCarry; in the function ThreadHandler, so maybe the variable i goes beyond what you think.

And in general, valgrind is a great tool for tracking memory management issues (of course if available on your system).

@edrezen Thanks that works by checking to make sure the carries array is at least the input size + 1 for every iteration.

At declaration, yes carries has one more item than inputNumbers but both vectors seem to have varying sizes while processing and at some point this invariant is no more true. You could add assert (carries.size() == input.size()+1); just before the line I pointed above (and add #include <cassert>) and see what happens.

Thanks for the help from @edrezen in finding the solution to my problem. I can't believe it was so simple. An index error. I updated the code slightly to fix this indexing error, the carries array should always be 1 larger than the input array. The updated code for the controller thread is shown below:
void ControllerThread(int &iterationCount, bool &finishedIterations, vector<int> &doneThreads, vector<int> &startIndexes, vector<int> &endIndexes, vector<uint8_t> &output, vector<uint8_t> &carries, bool &isAnyOne, int numThreads, vector<uint8_t> &input) {
    iterationCount = 0;
    while(iterationCount < totalIterations) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(mtx);
        cv.wait(lock, [&doneThreads] {
            // If all threads are done then start
            return all_of(doneThreads.begin(), doneThreads.end(), [](int done) {return done >= 1;});
        });

        // Carry propogation area
        while (isAnyOne) {
            isAnyOne = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < carries.size(); i++) {
                uint8_t intermediate;
                if (output.size() > i) {
                    intermediate = output.at(i) + carries.at(i);
                    carries[i] = 0;
                    uint8_t localCarry = (intermediate >= 10) ? 1 : 0;
                    if (localCarry == 1) {
                        isAnyOne = true;
                        intermediate -= 10;
                        if (carries.size() > i)
                            carries[i+1] = localCarry;
                        else
                            carries.push_back(localCarry);
                    }
                    output[i] = intermediate;
                }
                else if (carries[i] > 0) {
                    intermediate = carries.at(i);
                    carries[i] = 0;
                    output.push_back(intermediate);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        OutputList(output);

        if (iterationCount > 0) {
            input = output;
        }
        while (carries.size() < input.size() + 1) {
            carries.push_back(0);
        }
        // Set conditions for threads
        int itemsPerThread = input.size() / numThreads;
        // If the input size and number of threads aren't divisible
        int lastThreadExcess = input.size() % numThreads;
        // Initializing all the threads
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
            int startIndex = i * itemsPerThread;
            int endIndex = (i+1) * itemsPerThread;
            if (i == numThreads - 1) {
                endIndex += lastThreadExcess;
            }
            startIndexes[i] = startIndex;
            endIndexes[i] = endIndex;
        }
        // Resetting the threads to start doing tasks again
        for (int j = 0; j < doneThreads.size(); j++) {
            doneThreads[j] = 0;
        }
        // Starting the threads to do their tasks
        lock.unlock();
        cv.notify_all();
        iterationCount++;
    }
    // This top section of thread processing is finished so setting this variable
    finishedIterations = true;
}

